# Долгая загрузка изображения на странице

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! На странице изображение в шапке занимающее всю ширину экрана загружается долго при слабом интернете.
Проблема: когда изображение не загружено, то его высота равна 0 и блоки, находящиеся ниже прилипают к шапке, а когда изображение загружается, то блоки снова прыгают на место. См фото 1 и 2.
Вопрос: можно ли решить проблему, прописав для изображения или блока с изображением фиксированую высоту в 20vw?
[image: фото1]

[image: фото2]

Comment: Никогда не сталкивался с таким, но возможно смогу натолкнуть вас на мысль: если высота изображения статична, то можно обернуть его в некий div, высоту для которого статически указать по высоте изображения. А также накинуть на него backgorund-color. Например серый. Вторая идея заключается в использовании тега onload, можно передать ему процедуру, которая, скажем, обратится к элементу чз findElementById() и поместит некоторую секцию чз innerHTML. Хотя первый вариант, как по мне, лучше.

Comment: Вот я и хочу задать статичную высоту для блока, внутри которого лежит div, с помощью height:20vw. Это будет работать или нет? У меня нет возможности проверить(((

Comment: Ну по логике должно.

Comment: @GitRacoon: что-то неправильно в вашей вёрстке и/или стилях - картинки не должны распирать элементы. Наоборот, картинки должны быть чем-то ограничены. Так что ход мыслей верный - добавить размеры блоку с картинкой и сделать ему фон с градиентом, близким по цветам к картинке.